# avoid time/date overlapping in mysql (laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, laravel-5.3

I have an iOS app where users can reserve a car either daily or hourly and if a user reserves one car other user can't reserve it till the first reservation is over. I'm using Laravel as the API to save data to MySQL database.

The format of time and date are like this `27 Dec 2016` `15:21`. I'm saving the data

```
 public function requested(Request $request)
{
  $time = new Reservation();
  $time->from_date = $request->from_date;
  $time->to_date = $request->to_date;
  $time->from_time = $request->from_time;
  $time->to_time = $request->to_time;

}
```

but this won't prevent time overlapping for sure so I tried this

```
 $carCount = Reservation::where(

  function ($query) use ($startTime, $endTime) {
            $query->where('from_time', '<', $endTime)
                ->where('to_time', '>', $startTime);
        }
    )->count();


    if ($carCount > 0) {
        return response()->json(['request' => 'no']); // this response just to check 
    } else {
        $carRoom->save();
        response()->json(['request' => 'yes']);
    }
```

then I thought this isn't working because of date/time format. But I wanted to make sure what format I should convert the date in laravel?

this is my migration for Reservation:

```
         $table->string('from_date')->nullable();
        $table->string('to_date')->nullable();

        $table->string('from_time')->nullable();
        $table->string('to_time')->nullable();
```

I made the string because I wasn't sure if `Time` or anything is the right one

My main question is how can I avoid time and date overlapping in my app's database?

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all the PHP/Laravel stuff for the time being, and instead focus on getting a working MySQL query

Comment: you mean something like this `SELECT * FROM Reservation WHERE ((date_end > '" . $from_date . "') AND (date_start < '" . $to_date . "')) ";` ? or more complicated ? sorry I'm new to Laravel

Comment: Hm, well I guess :-)

Comment: how about the time? is it possible to do a combination of time and date check in one query ?

Comment: Store date and time as a single entity

Comment: WHat do you think about arcanine's answer `$query->where('reserve_from', '<',strtotime($user_from))->
                   where('reserve_to', '>', strtotime($user_to));` ? is this what you meant? Storing both entities as timestamps and do the query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132069/discussion-between-leo0019-and-strawberry).

Comment: That query snippet misunderstands the concept of overlapping ranges - but the idea of storing dates and times as a single entity is correct

Answer (score 1):

Store the dates in the database as timestamps 
then your query should work as intended then convert the incoming dates:

27 Dec 2016 15:21

to timestamps using strtotime() or with datetime objects
both are part of PHP check the PHP documentation to see more information.

Comment: thank you. Now I'm storing the date as timestamps. How doing two queries in one function to check if time and dates are not overlapping with other times and dates in the database?

Comment: oh I see you have your times and dates separated I didn't see that on my first reading of this question

Comment: I think I would personally store the datetime combination as start reservation and end reservation (as timestamp) 


then do SELECT COUNT(*) as pre_booked FROM reservations WHERE ? > reservation_start  AND ? < reservation_end

Comment: I like your idea! Do you think that the query `$query->where('from_time', '<', $endTime) ->where('to_time', '>', $startTime);` returns the correct answer ?

Comment: no because it doesn't take into account the date, you could do SELECT COUNT(*) as pre_booked FROM reservations WHERE ? > from_date + TIME_TO_SEC(from_time) AND ? < to_date + TIME_TO_SEC(to_time)

But it would be less efficient in this query than having just the two columns be time and date together instead of the current four columns.

Comment: found this answer somewhere and I kind of think it's the solution for my question `SELECT *
FROM mytable a
JOIN mytable b on a.starttime <= b.endtime
and a.endtime >= b.starttime
and a.name != b.name;` How would you implement this in my situation ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132011/discussion-between-arcanine-and-leo0019).

Comment: Should I store "reserveFrom" as timestamps? or string? What that effect the way I find the date/time falls between the dates and time in database ?